# SFML 2.1 how to make one sprite face another sprite

Tags: c++, rotation, sprite, sfml, trigonometry

I am trying to make a shooter game, and while trying to code the enemies
to face towards the player, I tried to use trigonometry to find the necessary rotation, but the code didn't work, and the enemy rotated erratically. This is the code:

```
void face(sf::Sprite& target, sf::Sprite& subject){
    int adjacent = subject.getPosition().x - target.getPosition().x;
    int opposite = target.getPosition().y - subject.getPosition().y;

    if (opposite == 0){
        opposite++;
    }
    if (adjacent == 0){
        adjacent++;
    }

    //if (adjacent < 0){
        //adjacent += 180;
    //}
    float result=atan(/*opposite / adjacent*/adjacent/opposite)*180/PI;

    subject.setRotation(result);
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `adjacent` and `opposite` should be floats because the position of a `sf::Sprite` are floats.

Answer (score 0):

You must use float with adjacent and opposite. And change result with this:

```
float angle = atan(adjacent / opposite) * 180 / PI;

if (opposite > 0)
    angle += 180;
```